# Get currently logged in user information in ektron

Tags: api, ektron

I have an ektron application in which I need to get the detailed information of a user who is currently logged in. I want the information such as username, email, display name, user id etc.
How can I do this using ektron api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Framework API. Take a look at:

```
Ektron.Cms.Framework.Context.UserContextService.Current
```

This will give you everything you're asking for. Here's a screenshot of the properties I have available to me in a v8.7 installation. Should be available all versions v8.5 and up. http://screencast.com/t/TcSdTySH9R

Comment: I need to get the email id and time zone also.

Comment: I have just done like this: var userId = Ektron.Cms.Framework.Context.UserContextService.Current.UserId;
Ektron.Cms.API.User.User user = new Ektron.Cms.API.User.User();
email = user.GetUser(userId).Email;